# System.out and .err - Back to the future?

Tags: java, multithreading, console, synchronization

At the very beginning of my program, I print out these two lines:

> Dyvil Compiler 1.0.0 for Dyvil 1.0.0
>
> Loading Configuration File from 'config.txt'

The first is printed in `System.err`, while the second is in `System.out`. Both `println` calls happen in the `main` method *in the above order*. However, it appears that the messages are sometimes swapped:

> Loading Configuration File from 'config.txt'
>
> Dyvil Compiler 1.0.0 for Dyvil 1.0.0

This happens when running the program in Eclipse Debug mode or from a Gradle build script (I haven't tested it with the `java` command). Note that absolutely no multithreading is involved, so don't tell me about the definition of insanity.

What is going on here?

Comment: depends on when the output buffers get flushed, probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two streams are exactly that, two **different** streams. As a result, if you eventually merge them together into a console output of some sort then it is perfectly feasable for the lines to appear out of order.

Both `System.out` and `System.err` are `PrintStream`s and are therefore almost certainly buffered so it just depends on when they get flushed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Eclipse - "ordering of output sent to stdout and stderr  is not deterministic".  See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9720

Answer (score -1):

You could always just add the `sleep(#ofseconds)` command just before the second `println` but after the first `println` to make sure it gets printed second. That will print the first line, wait however many seconds you choose, then print the second line. Its kind of a work around but it might fix the problem.

Comment: More reliable to use `flush()`.

Comment: `sleep()` seldom fixes any problem:  It usually just makes the problem less likely to occur.  Maybe a lot less likely.  In my world, that means, a lot less likely to occur in _testing_.  So, if the problem ever _does_ occur, it probably will happen at a customer site.  :-O